# List of Links that I want to Hyperlink to one column in excel of the same length

Tags: python, hyperlink, openpyxl

My problem is I am trying to set hyperlinks for the values(ID'S) in one column of a excel document with a list of links that I have and then be able to still see the values but they are now hyperlinked with my list of links.

I have tried combing/looking at other people who have similar issues on stackoverflow but I am stuck and have been on this issue way too long. 
I have looked here: [Stack Overflow Resource 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802296/hyperlink-style-in-openpyxl), [Stack Overflow Resource 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns), and [Stack Overflow Resource 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077661/adding-hyperlinks-in-some-cells-openpyxl?rq=1)

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook("pd1.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active
row_count = sheet.max_row
for i in range(2,row_count): #starting at 2 becasue row one has headers
  sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value.hyperlink = AURL_1_Links 

#AURL_1_Links is just a list of website links
```

When I exectue the code above I also get: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hyperlink'

The expected results will be my original excel file but the values in the ID column will now have hyperlinks attached to the given ID. So when you click on the ID you will be directed to the given web page belonging to that ID.

Comment: `sheet.cell()` is the cell object with the `hyperlink` and `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oye I am silly. I threw the whole list of links at it without iterating through the list of links. Also, added the hyperlink style.  Here is my working code:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook("pd1.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active
row_count = sheet.max_row
for i in range(2,row_count+1): #starting at 2 because row one has headers
  sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).hyperlink = AURL_1_Links[i-2]
  sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).style = "Hyperlink"
workbook.save("pd1.xlsx")
```

Comment: How you have created the AURL_1_Links[i-2] because openpyxl needs a specific format to read links like : link = "#'sheet_name'!B5"